# Modifying model causes project not to build

Tags: c#, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm working with code that was started by someone other than me, so I'm not entirely familiar with the structure. However, I decided I needed to change one of the variables in one of the models. I needed to switch it from

```
    [ForeignKey("JobFunctionDemandId")]
    public virtual JobFunctionDemand JobFunctionDemand { get; set; }

    public int JobFunctionDemandId { get; set; }
```

to

```
    [ForeignKey("SpecificRequirementId")]
    public virtual SpecificRequirement SpecificRequirement { get; set; }

    public int SpecificRequirementId { get; set; }
```

I thought this would be a relatively small change. I realized, however, that these variables correspond to tables in a database, and so I switched all instances of JobFunctionDemand and JobFunctionDemandId to SpecificRequirement and SpecificRequirementId respectively. However, now when I try to run the Update-Database command in the package manager console, I get the error "The project 'ProjectName' failed to build."

I'm guessing the issue here is that I'm modifying the structure of an existing database, but I'm not really sure how to fix it.

Comment: The issue rather seems to be that some other code is relying on the `JobFunctionDemand` parameter, which you just removed, causing the code to fail to build.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anywhere else where something of the type this model defines tries to access either JobFunctionDemand or JobFunctionDemandId. I used a search through the entire solution and none of the results were related to this model.

Comment: Well what are the errors then if you hit Build?

Comment: So, I figured out that issue--can't believe I didn't actually think to look at the build errors...Now I'm getting `Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss`